# MSVC fails to do math dependent on template parameters, is this a bug?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I couldn't find a very fitting title for this question without making it too long, so that's why it may not be very accurate. I have a class `clamped_value`, which stores a value and makes sure the value stays within a compile-time known bound. Now I'm using this class like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    using value_type = int;
    using percent_type = clamped_value<value_type, 0, 100>;
};
```

This all works fine, and I proceeded to add a `Precision` template parameter to `SomeClass`

```
template<int Precision>
class SomeClass
{
    using value_type = int;
    using percent_type = clamped_value<value_type, 0, 100 * (Precision + 1)>;
};
```

Suddenly the code breaks! Giving lots of errors about functions in `clamped_value.hpp` already being defined (I am sure the header guards are correct there). I decided to test the code using Gcc ([see coliru example here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87af127e1d4d2485)), and it worked just fine. Compiling with Clang also worked. Is this a bug in MSVC?

MSVC Version is 15.7.2.

**UPDATE**

I created a small example to model what I'm doing, and the problem is gone:

```
template<class T, int N, int M>
class clamped_value
{
public:
#define GEN_F(f) void f() {}

    GEN_F(a)
    GEN_F(b)
};

template<int N = 0>
class SomeClass
{
    using percent_type = clamped_value<int, 0, 100 * N>;

public:
    SomeClass()
    {
        percent_type p;
        p.a();
    }
};



int main()
{
    SomeClass<> a;
}
```

Extra coliru link: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2d612a292e72198

New update: updating VS to latest version did not fix the issue. Making a better MCVE now.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] here?  There is a lot of unneeded code in your link and it doesn't include your `SomeClass`.

Comment: Yes, sure. Forgot about that.

Comment: @MivVG *Is this a bug in MSVC?* -- Version?  Updates and service packs applied?

Comment: @MivVG Can you add an example where the code does not work?

Comment: I'm trying, but I can't seem to find anything, which makes it extra weird. I am 100% sure the code worked before adding the math to that typedef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more work, I finally spotted what was wrong. First I managed to replicate the error on gcc [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/094b94b7fb509e1d). When starting to think more about this, I finally discovered it. In `clamped_value`, there is a macro:

```
#define GEN_ARITHMETIC_OP(op) \
template<typename Ty, Ty TMin, Ty TMax, typename U, U UMin, U UMax> \
friend constexpr detail::common_clamped_value_t<Ty, TMin, TMax, U, UMin, UMax> \
operator op(clamped_value<Ty, TMin, TMax> const& lhs, clamped_value<U, UMin, UMax> const& rhs) \
{ \
    auto val = detail::common_clamped_value_t<Ty, TMin, TMax, U, UMin, UMax>(lhs.m_value op rhs.m_value); \
    val.clamp(); \
    return val; \
}
```

Now, the problem here is that the first `clamped_value` is templated, and thus works for all `clamped_value`'s. So if I instantiate only one `clamped_value`, everything works. But from the moment I use a new set of template parameters, the macro gets expanded *again*, and the operator is defined twice. A simple fix was to change the macro definition to only work for the currently instantiated type:

```
#define GEN_ARITHMETIC_OP(op) \
template<typename U, U UMin, U UMax> \
friend constexpr detail::common_clamped_value_t<T, Min, Max, U, UMin, UMax> \
operator op(clamped_value const& lhs, clamped_value<U, UMin, UMax> const& rhs) \
{ \
    auto val = detail::common_clamped_value_t<T, Min, Max, U, UMin, UMax>(lhs.m_value op rhs.m_value); \
    val.clamp(); \
    return val; \
}
```